# May i know why is my ajax called two time? or is actually normal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am new to js.
I am trying to call the API and save the data in a variable (obj = [])
But i go thru the console, my ajax call called two times. May i know why?

This is the console on my browser that i found out it is called two time:
[image: console on my browser]

Below is my code:

```
$(function (){
    var obj = [];
    var selected = $("select.dr-down option:selected").click().val();
    var markup = '';
    getAPI();

    console.log('obj = ', obj);

    function getAPI() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.mocky.io/v2/5d73bf3d3300003733081869',
            method: 'GET',
        }).done(function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (data) {
                obj.push(data);
            });
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you share more code as to when it has been invoked ..

Comment: @SoumenMukherjee this is all the code in my .js

Comment: I have tried this code in JSBin and the network call is executed only once. From your console it looks like the whole function is invoked twice.

Comment: Create an online demo and share it here it will be easy to debug. 

For ex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_jquery_editor.php

Comment: @Charlie really? do you know why is this happening?  is it becoz of my browser?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke this function on a button click? Because right now this is a self invoking function. If you want to invoke this function when a page loads please take a look at document.ready in jQuery

Comment: Keep function getAPI() outside the main $(function ().